# How can I make a custom subclass of uitextfield and over there using @IBDesignable & @IBInspectable I can set placholder padding from left

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I want to make a subclass of UITextField and over there by using @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable set the left side as well as right side padding for the text as well as placeholder. Can ignore left and right view.

Comment: You can use 
func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect for placeholder

Comment: This is for Text:
func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom class for your textfield and give your textfield class as `CustomTextField`.

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

  @IBInspectable var padding : CGFloat = 0 {
      didSet{
              let paddingView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: padding, height: self.frame.size.height))
              self.leftView = paddingView
              self.rightView = paddingView
              self.leftViewMode = .always
    }
  }
 }
```

Then, you can set padding from storyboard. And placeholder can be set from `Attributes Inspector` in storyboard.